# One or more required office components failed to complete successfully error during uninstallation of SharePoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint

I am trying to uninstall SharePoint 2016 as it is consuming a lot of RAM (Requires 16 gb and I have only 8 gb of RAM). I want to install SharePoint 2013 on my system.

But, whenever I am trying to uninstall it, I am getting message:

> "One or more required office components failed to complete successfully. For more information, consult the setup log file

I don't know, why this error message is coming. I checked some features like Configuration Wizard are still existing. Hhow to remove SharePoint 2016 completely so that I can do a fresh installation of SharePoint 2013?

[image]

Comment: Not a programming question. So you're in the wrong place. Also, it tells you to read the log... and you have not mentioned anything what the log says. Didn't you even read it?

Answer (score 0):

Solved! Just need to stop all the SQL services in services.msc
And the issue got resolved.